# Nutch retrieve too many duplicate images

Tags: image, duplicates, web-crawler, html, nutch

I am trying to retrieve images with Nutch. The plugin is just searching for the required images and retrieving their urls. What I get at the end contains too many duplicate urls. It retrieved 43 thousand urls and 39 thousand of them were duplicates. 
Is this normal or there could be some fault in the code I wrote (which I don't think is the case), Or other wise some problem with the Nutch itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be for instance that the same images are referenced multiple times?, in which case your results could be perfectly normal, I guess that running a test example on a given/known set of URLs could provide you with a better answer, limit your crawl only the the URLs on the seed file run a test and check which images are being crawled. What is the size of your crawl? Are you fetching already fetched pages or focusing on not yet visited pages? Are you ignoring small images like icons?

Keep in mind that usually on a website a lot of image assets are reused over and over again, specially if the website isn't t

Comment: Yeah seems like the problem is that images are used over and over again. I am ignoring thumbnails, icons, PNG's and even GIF's. Those filtered images contain even more duplicates.

Comment: On my side, I thought one thing could be my fault but didn't bother to test, I removed jpeg and jpg from the conf files which restrict Nutch to crawl them, i.e. I allowed Nutch to crawl the images, while my code in another way detects image and may be this causes the system to consider most of the image twice. Do you think this may be one of the issues?

Comment: Yep this could be, you're detecting the image with your custom plugin, then Nutch is finding that link anyway and at some point, it will fetch/parse that file. But if you've defined on Solr the URL as an id it shouldn't cause any duplicated, but if you store on a file/something could be. Keep in mind that in your case perhaps allowing Nutch to fetch/parse the actual image may not be necessary because in there you're not going to find any more links.